# Facebook Auth returns invalid credentials on one environment but success on the other

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, facebook-authentication

I own a Rails application that is using omniauth-facebook. We have a test environment and a production environment. Test environment URL is http://test.appname.com and production environment URL is http://appname.com. Both are running the exact same copy of code and they share the Facebook App ID and Secret. Recently, we noticed that FB login is failing on production with the message "invalid credentials" but it seems to work just fine on test. This is affecting all FB accounts. I tried removing our app from the user's allowed apps and adding it back but that did not seem to make any difference. Also, the URL generated:

Prod:
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request?app_id=298807996812584&display=page&next=http%3A%2F%2F21habit.com%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&response_type=code&perms=email%2Coffline_access&fbconnect=1

Test:
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request?app_id=298807996812584&display=page&next=http%3A%2F%2Ftest.21habit.com%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&response_type=code&perms=email%2Coffline_access&fbconnect=1

are the same except the "next" param points to different URLs. I am unable to figure out why this is happening. Has anyone else experienced this/knows why this is happening/how I can debug this?

Comment: There was a similar post a month ago , which mentioned something about expired test period . Check facebook API settings if this login failure happened recently . I'll try to find the post for you.

Comment: What is the Site URL set for the facebook app you created at https://developers.facebook.com/apps? You should have as many facebook apps as environments. So in this case you should have 2 facebook apps with different IDs, Secrets and Site URLs.